# CPLEX Fix variables and keep MIP Start

Tags: c++, cplex

I fix variables to their optimal values from the last solve using

```
x_val = cplex.getValue(x[a]);
x[a].setBounds(x_val,x_val);
```

However, this results in Warnings "No solution found from ... MIP starts." When I remove the variables from the model instead of fixing them, i.e. `x[a].end();` the MIP starts still work. How can fix variables without destroying the MIP starts? This should be possible when fixing them to the optimal values from the last solve, shouldn't it?

Comment: I have had this issue before. This approach has helped me in the past. It is safer to add a small 'epsilon' value around the optimal value that you are trying to fix, something like bounds of (1+epsilon)*x and (1-epsilon)*x where epsilon is something like 10e-5

Comment: That fixed it, and I haven't found a better strategy so far. Thank you!